# Static Class Non-Static Member

Tags: java, static

I'm reading a book on android game development and I've come across the first patch of code:

```
public static class KeyEvent {
    public static final int KEY_DOWN = 0;
    public static final int KEY_UP = 1;

    public int type;
    public int keyCode;
    public char keyChar;
}
```

It is my understanding that anything static means there can only be one instance of it.

If there can only ever be one instance of `KeyEvent` why are `type`, `keyCode` and `keyChar` not declared static as well?

Comment: Is this an *inner class*? i.e. is it contained within another class?

Comment: static doesn't mean the same thing when applied to a nested class. Read the tutorial about nested classes: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only nested classes can be declared as `static`; not outer/normal classes. It allows you to use the static inner class without instantiating the outer class.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is an `nested class`. `static` modifier means here that this class is accessible without creating outer class object.

Assuming that outer class is called `OuterClass` you can call:

```
KeyEvent ke = new OuterClass.KeyEvent();
```

Comment: No, it's a nested class - it's *not* an inner class, precisely because of the static modifier.

Comment: @JonSkeet More precisely: it's a _static nested class_. Inner class is also nested class, because according to [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html), Nested classes are devided into two categories: static nested classes and non-static nested classes. The non-static nested classes are called _inner classes_.

Comment: @MockerTim: Yup. Anonymous inner classes are also inner classes, but bizarrely enough if you create an anonymous inner class from a static method, it's an inner class with out an enclosing instance. (I had previously thought that inner => has enclosing instance, but apparently not...)

Answer (score 0):

`static` **does not** really mean "there can only be one instance of it".

If you are using the static keyword in any declaration **within** a class, `static` means "what I declare here is not a member of an instance of the enclosing class, but it is a member **of the class itself**."

That being said, if you're declaring a nested class (a class within a class) as static, then it means that the nested class declaration does not rely on an instance of the enclosing class, and can be instantiated directly.